# Last day getting dropped while casting varchar 2 date format 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a varchar2 date field 'Created_Date' of the format 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI' in an oracle table.Now, I want all the fields where date range is between 1-JAN-2014 to 31-MAR-2014.

I have used the below query & I know some of my dates of 31st March 2014 are getting missed.

```
Select * 
from Table1
where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') between '1-JAN-2014' and '31-MAR-2014'
```

Please suggest on the same. Thanks.

Comment: varchar2 is NOT a date column. Text and dates are not the same thing. Also, you shouldn't tag this with sql server since you are clearly using Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is happening is that your `VARCHAR2` "dates" have time components, in which case they could fall after 31 March 2014. I would suggest you do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
 WHERE TO_DATE(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') >= '01-JAN-2014'
   AND TO_DATE(created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') < '01-APR-2014'
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course dates on Mar 31 are not shown -- if they have a time component.  By using `between` you are only getting up to midnight when Mar 31st begins.  That is how dates work and how between works.

Here are two solutions.  First, only use the date:

```
where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') between date '2014-01-01' and date '2014-03-31'
```

Or phrase it a bit differently:

```
where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') >= date '2014-01-01' and
      to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') < date '2014-04-01'
```

Notice that I also switched from using the string constant to the `date` operator.  This keyword allows you to provide a date constant in ISO-standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

My preference is a combination of these two methods:

```
where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= date '2014-01-01' and
      to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') < date '2014-04-01'
```

In general, I try to avoid using `between` with dates, precisely because of this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the records up to and including `31-MAR-2014 00:00`, but you want to include all the times of that last day also.

Get the records up to (but not including) `00:00` the next day:

```
where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') >= '1-JAN-2014' and
  to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') < '1-APR-2014'
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, never store dates in a text field (ie varchar2), that's just asking for trouble.

In any case, it's not picking up Mar 31, 2014, since all dates have a time component.

Your actual data has some time, let's assume 10am, on Mar 31.
You then ask it to retrieve all items LESS than Mar 31, 2014 .. no time component, therefore it assumes "00:00:00" or midnight.

Since 10am is 10 hours after midnight ... it's not earlier.

You probably want:

```
  Select * 
  from Table1
  where to_date(Created_Date, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
        between to_date('01-JAN-2014','dd-mon-yyyy')
             and to_date('31-MAR-2014','dd-mon-yyyy')+1;
```

Always convert to dates yourself, never rely on implicit conversion.
Then just "+1" to move to next day, and you'll get all records "Prior to Apr 1", which is what you want ... any time, on Mar 31.